# Multiply by a percentage

Tags: percentages

Ok, so this is pretty trivial but my head is battered so need some help!

What calculation is the equivalent of $30,000 \times 0.073\%$?

I am a PHP programmer and cannot simply do $ 30000\times 0.073\%$. I need the straight math for it.

I look forward to being ridden of this small pain in my temple!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

30000*0.00073 - a percentage is just a proportion eg 40% is 0.4, just move the decimal point two spaces to the left.

Comment: Thank you! I tried that but forgot I had 2 variables using percent and I only changed one... DOH! :)

Answer (score 2):

Let me try ! As its name says, a percentage is a ... percentage (be sure that I am not joking). So, what it means is that $x$%  of $100$ units correspond to $x$ units.

So, if you have to compute $A \times x$%, just compute $A \times \frac{x}{100}$